# Why is 'curl' not recognized when running in Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, curl

I am trying to run a Curl command wrapped inside Ruby code as below:

```
 f=IO.popen("C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -H 'Authorization: Bearer #{token}' -s -v -D - http://api.pageuppeople.com/v1/NAS/Config/LanguageDictionary/Overrides --debug 2>NUL").readlines
```

However, the output I get is:

```
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I am running on Windows 7.

I also have "C:\Windows\System32" set in the environment path.

Please help.

Comment: Does "C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe" actually exist in that location.  I don't think that is something that comes standard with Windows.

Comment: Unless you *have* to do something else, use the Requests package for Python to do your fetching. It's a much cleaner approach to solve the problem. If you can't use Requests, the builtin `httplib` isn't as nice but still better than shelling out to use curl.

Comment: The [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem is a great way to interface with libcurl and works more conveniently than trying to use `popen`.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is not a component of Windows. Unless you have specifically installed it, it won't exist on the system.

I am not a Ruby expert, but I suspect that you should really be using the [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/) Ruby library here, or something similar to it. Even on a system where `curl` is installed, launching it is not a sensible way of running an HTTP request.

Comment: Ruby has a great gem called [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) which directly interfaces with libcurl. It's very full featured and can do some things that Net::HTTP can't.

Comment: it actually works in powershell without a pre-install

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Sort of. It's an alias to a Powershell command (`Invoke-WebRequest`). It'll work for some very simple `curl` commands, but don't expect it to work if you're doing anything fancy.

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense. i have been trying -X POST that got me here. now I need to use curl to download curl :)

Answer (score 1):

Curl does not come with Windows, but it has been ported to Windows.

You can download it here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/file
```

I know nothing about Ruby, but I do know you shuld be using a native libary for your HTTP needs.

Answer (score 0):

CURL is not a Windows component. Download curl.exe and keep it in your path.

Alternatively download curl.exe and invoke the command from the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 now provides `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` but I still see that error message when I try to call it from a service (Jenkins user in my case).
I'll post an update when I find out something more (e.g. which user rights are necessary).

I've installed curl now with chocolatey. See https://chocolatey.org/packages/curl.